# Null strings may not be marshaled in Windows Runtime arguments. Parameter name: sourceString

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

In application,  I tried to bind some value but I saw there did not find any value when I saw in exception log then I found error
-> **Null strings may not be marshaled in Windows Runtime arguments. Parameter name: sourceString**

this is part of my code where I got error

```
private void BindResidentInformation(bool isDrugRecordBook)
    {
        try
        {                                            
                if (isDrugRecordBook)
                    pageTitle.Text = "DRUG RECORD BOOK (READMISSION)";
                else
                    pageTitle.Text = "READMISSION";

                dynamicTitle.Text = " READMISSION";

                residentinfostackpanel.Visibility = spNewAdmissoncondition.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                reAdmissionResidentStackpanel.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(PageNewAdmission._reAdmissionGetResidentByIDViewModel.Allergy))
                    txtAllergy.Text = PageNewAdmission._reAdmissionGetResidentByIDViewModel.Allergy;

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(PageNewAdmission._reAdmissionGetResidentByIDViewModel.FirstName))
                    txtFirstName.Text = PageNewAdmission._reAdmissionGetResidentByIDViewModel.FirstName;

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(PageNewAdmission._reAdmissionGetResidentByIDViewModel.LastName))
                    txtLastName.Text = PageNewAdmission._reAdmissionGetResidentByIDViewModel.LastName;

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(PageNewAdmission._reAdmissionGetResidentByIDViewModel.UnitName))
                    txtUnit.Text = PageNewAdmission._reAdmissionGetResidentByIDViewModel.UnitName;

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(PageNewAdmission._reAdmissionGetResidentByIDViewModel.RoomNo))
                {
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(PageNewAdmission._reAdmissionGetResidentByIDViewModel.Bed))
                        txtRoom.Text = Convert.ToString(PageNewAdmission._reAdmissionGetResidentByIDViewModel.RoomNo) + "-" + PageNewAdmission._reAdmissionGetResidentByIDViewModel.Bed;
                    else
                        txtRoom.Text = Convert.ToString(PageNewAdmission._reAdmissionGetResidentByIDViewModel.RoomNo);
                }

                if (PageNewAdmission._reAdmissionGetResidentByIDViewModel.BirthDate != null)
                    txtDOB.Text = Convert.ToDateTime(PageNewAdmission._reAdmissionGetResidentByIDViewModel.BirthDate).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(PageNewAdmission._reAdmissionGetResidentByIDViewModel.Doctor))
                    txtPhysician.Text = PageNewAdmission._reAdmissionGetResidentByIDViewModel.Doctor;

                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(PageNewAdmission._reAdmissionGetResidentByIDViewModel.ProvincialHealthCard))
                    txtHCN.Text = Regex.Replace(PageNewAdmission._reAdmissionGetResidentByIDViewModel.ProvincialHealthCard, "[^0-9]", "");

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(PageNewAdmission._reAdmissionGetResidentByIDViewModel.VersionCode))
                    txtVersionCode.Text = PageNewAdmission._reAdmissionGetResidentByIDViewModel.VersionCode;

                //if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(PageNewAdmission._reAdmissionGetResidentByIDViewModel.Condition))
                txtConditionBlock.Text = PageNewAdmission._reAdmissionGetResidentByIDViewModel.Condition;

                //if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(PageNewAdmission._reAdmissionGetResidentByIDViewModel.LUCode))
                //    txtLimitedCode.Text = PageNewAdmission._reAdmissionGetResidentByIDViewModel.LUCode;
           
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            new ExceptionHelper().AddException(ex.Message, this.ToString(), "BindResidentInformation");
        }
    }
```

Please Let me know if there is any mistake.

Thank You
& Best Wishes

Comment: I can't tell where the issue is because only you have the real data. But you could try to put a breakpoint at the beginning of the code and then try to debug the code line by line. Based on the error message, there should be a null string that causes the issue.

Comment: @RoyLi-MSFT Thank you for your consideration .also  I tried with breakpoint and Did not found issue. This error occur randomly not everytime.

Comment: It's hard to locate the issue if you can't reproduce this issue. Since you've already handled the exception, I'd suggest you save the data model to log when the exception is thrown. So that you could check the model data for more details.